# Center a div with fixed menu on the side

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a website with a fixed "sidebar" on the left side and the "content" centered both vertically and horizontally on the remaining part (to the right) of the website. I want the "content" to always be centered no matter the size of the screen. I have tried margin-left:auto; and margin-right:auto; but when I do this the content positions itself on top of the sidebar. Can anyone help me? Here is a link to an image to show what I mean https://www.dropbox.com/s/95duw8yrmlwtc26/Sk%C3%A4rmavbild%202015-01-22%20kl.%2011.51.10.png?dl=0. Here is the code i have at the moment, where the sidebar is "aside" and the content is everything within "main":

```
<aside> this box should always be fixed on the left and have a height of     100%. 

</aside><!--end side--> 


<main>

<div id="submenu">
<ul>
<li>LOGOS</li>
<li>PRINT</li>
<li>WEB DESIGN</li>
<li>ALL</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="content">
<ul>
<li><img src="img1" alt="img1"/></li>
<li> <img src="img2" alt="img2"/></li>
<li> <img src="img3" alt="img3"/></li>
</ul>
</div><!--end content-->
</main>

aside{
background-color:#3A364F;
width:340px;
height:100%;
min-height:710px;
position:fixed;
float:left;

}
main {
width:67%;
float:left;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
```

Comment: What is your `aside` thing in the CSS part?

Comment: Sorry I had missed it in the html. Now I have added it. The aside is the fixed sidebar on the side. While everything in main is the part that should be centered.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a good solution, if you're up to using CSS3 (which isn't "officially" out yet, but most if not all browsers support it):

```
div#submenu {
    background-color:#3A364F;
    width:340px;
    height:100%;
    min-height:710px;
    position:fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color:blue;
}
div.content {
    margin-left:340px;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color:red;
}
```

I set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6sq6gdux/) to demonstrate this code.

`margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto` only works if the object it is put on has a specified width (ie, not percentage). I believe that using a `calc(...)` will ultimately resolve into a "specified width." If you mean that you want the content actually *centred* within the remaining area (and not just taking up all of the space that the submenu isn't taking), what you could do then would be to add another `<div>` inside the red `<div class="content">` which has rules then to position the nested `<div>` inside its red parent.

Another issue with the code might be that you're applying CSS rules to objects that don't exist; I assume you want the rule `aside` to apply to the submenu and `main` to apply to `content`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am not sure I was clear enough on explaining what I meant (my bad!) and from your jsFiddle it doesn't look like we mean the same thing. I have edited/updated the question and added a link to a image demonstrating what I am trying to do. I would appreciate if you take a look. Also, I have tried with a specified width on "main", and the margin-left:auto adn margin-right:auto still don't work. What happens is that it positions itself behind the aside.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you also can look at a good Framework to create your website. Lots of frameworks have templates and good documentation to build the site. 
Good frameworks are Bootstrap, Foundation and Skeleton.

If you wish to stick to your current build, the solution of Alec, where you actually calculate the remaining space around the given measurement of 340px;